# Trying to get single page details using wordpress and nextjs using apollo graphQL

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js, graphql, apollo-client

I am tryring to get single page details using **wordpress** and **nextjs** using **apollo** graphQL, But getting error.

Error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
const { alllPost } = useQuery(getAllPostsWithSlug);

return {
paths: alllPost.edges.node.map(({ node }) => `/posts/${node.slug}`) || [],
fallback: true,
};
}
```

Is anyone have same issue? Please help.

Comment: `useQuery` is a custom React hook and cannot be used inside `getStaticPaths`. React hooks can only be used inside React components or other React hooks.